# Regex: Match a specific character then a number

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match a specific character with a number followed by a full stop, i.e. `V1.` or `V2.`

I decided to start with just trying to match the character and number but it doesnt seem to be working, after numerous Google searches I believe this to be correct but obviously it isnt. TIA

```
var regex = new Regex("\b[V][0-9]\b")
var replaced = regex.Replace(path, string.Empty);
```

Comment: What do you want to match? Only V?

Comment: I want to match `V[0-9].`

Comment: You didnot escape `.`.use `\.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would match `V` plus the ollowing one or more numbers only if it's followed by a dot.

```
new Regex(@"\bV\d+\.")
```

**Explanation:**

- `\b` Word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.
- `V` Matches a literal `V`
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits. Use only `\d` if the following number is a single digit number.
- `\.` Matches a literal dot.

Comment: This almost works, but I need to match the `.` too.  Can you explain how this works and mine does?

Comment: You forget to add `\.` and also you need to include the pattern within a verbatim string like `@"pattern"` or otherwise you need to escape the backslash one more time.